# Pytest how to switch between live production database and test database?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I am looking for a way to switch between the production database and the testing database in order to test all of my code.

I have an API that communicates with a database via SqlAlchemy. Each function in the API can take a database session as an argument, by default this uses the production database, but for testing I can pass in a test session instead to override it. This was all working quite well, however, when it comes to testing functions that utilise the api I am now faced with the issue of adding a database argument for every function just so it can pass that through to the api call when testing. Is there a better workflow?

Comment: Different database configurations, selected by an environment variable?